# Search by values in Redis cache - Secondary Indexing

Tags: caching, redis, full-text-search, key-value-store

I am new to Redis. I want to search by one or multiple values that comes from API. 
e.g - Let's say that I want to store some sec data as below:

```
    Value1
        {

        "isin":"isin123",
        "id_bb_global":"BBg12345676",
        "cusip":"cusip123",
        "sedol":"sedol123",
        "cpn":"0.09",
        "cntry":"US",
        "144A":"xyz",
        "issue_cntry":"UK"
        }

        Value2
        {

        "isin":"isin222",
        "id_bb_global":"BBG222",
        "cusip":"cusip222",
        "sedol":"sedol222",
        "cpn":"1.0",
        "cntry":"IN",
        "144A":"Y",
        "issue_cntry":"DE"
        }
...
...
```

I want to search by cusip or cusip and id_bb_global, ISIN plus Exchange, or sedol.

e.g - search query data -> {"isin":"isin222", "cusip":"cusip222"} ,  should return all data sets from value.

What is the best way to store this kind of data structure in Redis and API to retrieve the same faster.

Comment: You can follow the patterns described at https://redis.io/topics/indexes or try something that is built for this like https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch

Comment: Thanks @itamar Haber. Would redisearch non enterprise verserion work  on cluster multiple cluster?

Comment: "Would redisearch non enterprise verserion work on cluster multiple cluster?" <- No, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

when you insert data, you can create sets to maintain the index.

```
{

        "isin":"isin123",
        "id_bb_global":"BBg12345676",
        "cusip":"cusip123",
        "sedol":"sedol123",
        "cpn":"0.09",
        "cntry":"US",
        "144A":"xyz",
        "issue_cntry":"UK"
        }
```

example for the above data, if you wnat to filter by `isin` and `cusip`, you can create the respective set for `isin:123` and `cusip:123` and add that item id to both of those sets.

later on, if you want to find item that are in both `isin:123` and `cusip:123`, you just have to run `SINTER` on those 2 sets.

Or if you want to find items that are either in `isin:123` OR `cusip:123`, you can union them.

Comment: Coduld you please provide me an example on how to insert the entire payload (e.g- value 1) as a set and retrieve the same with one or multiple attributes. Thanks !!

Comment: I have an example on my blog here https://tuananh.org/2018/06/12/advanced-filtering-and-sorting-with-redis-part-1/